# Nodejs (Typescript+vscode) Debugging: How to resolve source maps for two different directories?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, source-maps

I have two projects. The first project is a web-server that runs scripts. The second project exposes a collection of scripts that the first project runs.

I launch the web-server via a `.vscode/launch.json` entry.
I reference the program as `${workspaceFolder:first}/src/webserver.ts` and reference the compiled js as `outFiles: [ "{workspaceFolder:first}/**/*.js" ]`.

The webserver gets the request and launches the js file in the second project directory but doesn't use the source that's referenced by the source map.

If I try to add multiple outFiles the program tries to run the `webserver.ts` file instead of the `.js` equivalent.

Can anyone shed some light on the process of how the vscode debugger handles finding source maps or knows of a solution to getting the source from the .js in a different project directory to get recognized by the debugger.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!